# C++ : gcc compiler warning for large stack allocation

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, gcc-warning

Consider:

```
void largestackallocation() {
    double a[10000000];
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling this with MSVC (Cl.exe and MSBuild.exe), a warning [C6262](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6262?view=msvc-170) is issued suggesting to move allocation to heap instead of the stack. The compilation is in release mode with the following options:

```
/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"E:\local\boost_1_72_0" /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /FA /Fp"x64\Release\windows.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

On gcc, with a release mode build with the option to even convert warnings to errors:

```
g++    -c -O2 -Werror -MMD -MP -MF "build/Release/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/largestackallocation.o.d" -o build/Release/GNU-Linux/_ext/511e4115/largestackallocation.o ../src/largestackallocation.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Release/GNU-Linux
```

no warning/errors are issued. What is the option/setting to make gcc/g++ issue warnings on potentially large stack allocations?

Comment: gcc has a `-Wstack-usage=<limit>` option.      For example, `-Wstack-usage=255` will give warnings if a functions stack usage exceeds 255 bytes.   Pick a limit that you consider is appropriately conservative.    The calculation done is conservative (i.e.  may sometimes over-estimate stack usage by a function), but also allows for dynamic stack allocation (VLAs, `alloc()`, etc).

Comment: @Peter I was just checking that, I don't get warnings then either : https://godbolt.org/z/9n6j56h89

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-Wlarger-than="max-bytes" might be what you're looking for. It warns you whenever an object is defined whose size exceeds "max-bytes".

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html seems to suggest that `-Wlarger-than=‘PTRDIFF_MAX’ is enabled by default. ` and yet the warning was not issued.

Comment: Yes, on explicitly stating -Wlarger-than=10000, the warning does get issued. This warning goes away if a is allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Tryer `10000000*sizeof(double)` is probably not greater than `PTRDIFF_MAX`, which is why the warning wasn't issued